# How to install "mFilter" package for R version 3.5.1?

Tags: r

I am trying to get hodrick-prescott filter for some time-series, I try to get the "mFilter" package but it says this:

```
package ‘mFilter’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

How can I get installed this package? is there other package who makes the same functions?

Greetings,
Alvaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using remotes library and then pulling the repo directly from github by using "install_github".

Here's the code:

```
library(remotes)
install_github("cran/mFilter")
library(mFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [mFilter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mFilter/index.html) package has been removed from the CRAN repository.

> Package ‘mFilter’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>   Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
>   Archived on 2018-07-20 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders.

You can still download the archived package from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mFilter/)

And install as per below (just update your path to the downloaded .tar.gz file as appropriate)

```
install.packages("C:/Users/xxx/xxx/mFilter_0.1-3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```